# IE javascript compatibility is killing me

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, internet-explorer

I left cross-browser compatiblity issues for last, and it seems IE is going to be a big pain. Nothing is working in IE;

First of all, the following is not working:

```
var img = document.createElement("img");
img.setAttribute("height", "270px");
```

I have an invisible div onmouseover which displays a transparent div "cpanel". I cant access that as well.

```
if(hover.addEventListener){
    hover.addEventListener('mouseover',function () {$('#cpanel').fadeIn("slow");/*Core.addClass(cpanel,"on");*/},false);
    hover.addEventListener('mouseout', function () {$('#cpanel').fadeOut("slow");/*Core.removeClass(cpanel,"on");*/},false);
}
else if(hover.attachEvent) {
    hover.attachEvent('onmouseover',function () {$('#cpanel').fadeIn("slow");/*Core.addClass(cpanel,"on");*/});
    hover.attachEvent('onmouseout', function () {$('#cpanel').fadeOut("slow");/*Core.removeClass(cpanel,"on");*/}); 
}
```

Maybe there are some z-index issues?

I am unable to find more bugs as IE is not moving to the later stages... :(

Comment: Can you make your question title a bit more descriptive? :)

Comment: @WowtaH, I thought it was just me... =)

Comment: As stated below in the answers, let jQuery do the hard work for you.Thats what it has been designed to do, take some of the pain out of cross-browser JS. See http://docs.jquery.com/Events and http://docs.jquery.com/Core/jQuery#htmlownerDocument. Hope that helps.

Answer (score 4):

Why are you attaching your event handlers manually when jquery (already on the page by the looks of it) can do it more reliably?

```
$(hover).mouseover(function () { $('#cpanel').fadeIn("slow"); });
$(hover).mouseout(function () { $('#cpanel').fadeOut("slow"); });
```

And for the image:

```
var img = $("<img />");
img.css("height", "270px");
```

Comment: i tried the above method. it works fine in FF but IE doesnt even recognise the empty div that is placed at the top of the image ("hover") that fades in the cpanel. is there some z-index hack i am missing?

Comment: Can you edit your question with the dom structure? I don't understand what you mean.

Answer (score 2):

The @height attribute (unlike height style property) accept numeric values only.

```
img.setAttribute("height", "270");
```

Answer (score 0):

Or combine them all

```
$('<img/>').height(270).append('body');
```

If no px is specified it is taken by default [jQuery height method](http://docs.jquery.com/CSS/height)

Or even

```
$('<img/>').css({'height':'270px'}).append('body');
```

Append (or prepend) to whatever you need to.

For the hover you are trying

```
var $cpanel = $('#cpanel');
$(div).hover(function(){//hover
$cpanel.fadeIn("slow");
},
function(){//hover out
$cpanel.fadeOut("slow");
});
```

The top line is to cache the panel in a var save looking it up 2 times.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you can try something like this... will take you to figure out how to implement... but a base variable declaration is there that you can use for javascript dom changes

```
 var cross=document.all? document.all.cpanel: document.getElementById("cpanel");

   cross.style.width=100 +"px";   //eg of setting style.width property
```

something like that might be a start in getting your object compatible for editing.